# Jqueryvalidate's .validate() method does not execute in ASP Core

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I'm trying to submit the form via ajax and it works fine but there was no validation. So I've added the JQuery validation library and added the code into handler as stated in the documentation but it doesnt seem to execute

The cshtml page:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "CreateProduct";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1 class="text-center">Create Product</h1>
<br>

<form method="post" id="formdata" asp-controller="Product" asp-action="UploadProduct">
    <div class="form-group">
        <p>Please provide a name for your product:</p>
        <input type="text" name="Name" required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <p>Please provide a price for your product:</p>
        <input type="number" name="Price" required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <p>Please provide a description for your product:</p>
        <input type="text" name="Description" required />
    </div>
</form>

<button class="btn btn-primary" id="subBtn">Upload Files</button>

@section scripts
{
    <script>
        $(function () {

            $('#subBtn').click(function (e) {
                var formData = $('#formdata').serialize();

                $('#formdata').validate({
                    debug: true,
                    submitHandler: function () {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: '/Product/UploadProduct',
                            data: formData,
                            success: function (e) {
                                Toastify({
                                    text: "Product submition successful!",
                                    duration: 3000,
                                    gravity: "bottom", // `top` or `bottom`
                                    position: 'right', // `left`, `center` or `right`
                                    backgroundColor: 'blue',//"linear-gradient(to right, #00b09b, #96c93d)",
                                    stopOnFocus: true, // Prevents dismissing of toast on hover
                                    onClick: function () { } // Callback after click
                                }).showToast();

                                $(':input', '#formdata')
                                    .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
                                    .val('')
                                    .prop('checked', false)
                                    .prop('selected', false);
                            }
                        }).fail(function (e) {
                            //toastr.error('Product not added');
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        });

    </script>
}
```

And I've added the reference to the _Layout.cshtml:

```
 <environment include="Development">
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/additional-methods.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
    </environment>
```

Once again I'd like to add that the logic is working, it's just that the validate() method doesn't execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.validate()` method is only used to initialize the plugin on your form. It does not belong inside of the click handler of the submit button. You should move the `validate()` method outside of the client handler , and serialize data inside the `submitHandler` event :

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#formdata').validate({


            submitHandler: function () {
                var formData = $('#formdata').serialize();
                alert("ad");
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/Product/UploadProduct',
                    data: formData,
                    success: function (e) {
                        Toastify({
                            text: "Product submition successful!",
                            duration: 3000,
                            gravity: "bottom", // `top` or `bottom`
                            position: 'right', // `left`, `center` or `right`
                            backgroundColor: 'blue',//"linear-gradient(to right, #00b09b, #96c93d)",
                            stopOnFocus: true, // Prevents dismissing of toast on hover
                            onClick: function () { } // Callback after click
                        }).showToast();

                        $(':input', '#formdata')
                            .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
                            .val('')
                            .prop('checked', false)
                            .prop('selected', false);
                    }
                }).fail(function (e) {
                    //toastr.error('Product not added');
                });
            }
        });

    });

</script>
```

You can then use submit button inside `form` tag to trigger submit :

```
<form method="post" id="formdata" asp-controller="Product" asp-action="UploadProduct">
    <div class="form-group">
        <p>Please provide a name for your product:</p>
        <input type="text" name="Name" required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <p>Please provide a price for your product:</p>
        <input type="number" name="Price" required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <p>Please provide a description for your product:</p>
        <input type="text" name="Description" required />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" id="ajaxsubBtn1">Upload Files</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. So the submitHandler is basically an override for the submit event I suppose. I wish it was a bit clearer in the documentation